# Apache Ant does not include any file using my pattern

Tags: apache, ant, build-automation

Here is zip task:

```
<zip destfile="${bindir}/HorizonWeb_bin.zip" >
  <fileset dir="${basedir}/Horizon WEB Deploy/Release" >
    <include name="*/*.bin" />
    <exclude name="*/*.pdb" />
  </fileset>
</zip>
```

What I do not understan is why it do not include any file while, for example, this one works:

```
<zip destfile="${bindir}/HorizonWeb.zip">
  <fileset dir="${basedir}/Horizon WEB Deploy/Release" />
</zip>
```

Could anybody explain and input a working example?

Thanks for any help ;)

P.S. Using Jenkins 1.424, if it matters....

Answer (score 2):

`*/*.bin` means all the files ending with `.bin` and being a a direct subdirectory of the fileset dir. Is it what you want?

Don't you rather want `**/*.bin`, which means any file ending with `.bin`, in the fileset dir or in any subdirectory of the fileset dir, recursively?

Comment: well, I tried both ways ... current directory will not contain any *.bin file anyway, so goal is any level subdirectory ... but I tried with the **/*.bin pattern it still did not work :( could it be causing other filesets or there is also some undocumented quirks here?

Comment: It's `**/*.bin`, not `**/.bin`.

Comment: @HX_unbanned This solution should work. Also you can try includes/excludes zip task's attributes.

Comment: Hmmm ... Okay ... I'll multi-check dir, vars, props, args and other "data-carriers" ...